# Converting to Maven Project from Java Project

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e

I have installed m2eclipse plugin. I tried to convert a java project into a maven project.Here is my pom.xml

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>SpringExample</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I clicked on configure and converted it into maven project , I found out that 2 folders have been generated bin & target and all the class files are in bin folder, target folder is empty & jar was not created.
This is the first time I'm trying to use maven and what I understand is that there should have been 2 folders generated src and target. 
I can't figure out what went wrong(I did not get any error).
I am using eclipse juno ,I have installed m2e version 1.3.1.x

Comment: Update your m2e installation cause current version is 1.6 Furthermore it would suggest to get an more up to date of Eclipse like Luna etc.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you read [Maven in 5 minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).
Converting the project will only generate the pom ("This wizard creates a new POM (pom.xml) descriptor for Maven.").

If you want to generate an project with the folder structure you have to use an maven archetype.

Example:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DgroupId=com.test -DartifactId=SpringExample -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar -DinteractiveMode=false
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your code under src/main/java. Tests should be under src/test/java. Your output is in target directory. Bin is generated by Eclipse not maven.
More about directory structure [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html)